# how to use Sed/gedit to remove everything after a " : " in a file and write output to another file?

Tags: awk, sed, gedit

i have a text file :

```
"postalAddress2": "Postal Address Line 2",
"postalCity": "Postal City",
"postalPostCode": "Postal Code",
"postalState": "State"
```

I need to remove the second column , ie, everything after " : "
and remove all newlines

expected output :

```
"postalAddress2","postalCity","postalPostCode","postalState"
```

Can this be done using sed or regex in gedit ?

i tried this regex but its not working:

```
.*\:(.*) \:.*
```

Comment: @Anti_cse51, could you please do check my solution once and lemme know if it helped you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following once.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":";OFS=","} {val=(val?val OFS:"")$1} END{print val}' Input_file
```

OR taking inspiration from @Sundeep's comments try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"} {print $1}'  Input_file | paste -sd,
```

Answer (score 1):

With sed and paste:

```
sed 's/:.*//' file | paste -d ',' -s > other_file
```

Output to other_file:

```
"postalAddress2","postalCity","postalPostCode","postalState"
```

Comment: or `cut -d: -f1 file | paste -sd,`

Comment: or `sed 's/:[^,]*//' file | paste -d '' -s`

Comment: or `perl -pe 's/:[^,]*//; s/,\n/,/' file`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tmp.txt
"postalAddress2": "Postal Address Line 2",
"postalCity": "Postal City",
"postalPostCode": "Postal Code",
"postalState": "State"

$ sed 's/\:.*$//' tmp.txt | tr '\n' ','
"postalAddress2","postalCity","postalPostCode","postalState",
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -Ez 's/:[^,]*//mg;s/,\n/,/g' file
```

Slurp the file into memory and using multiline mode, remove everything from the first `:` to next occurrence of a `,` on all lines.

Then replace `,\n`'s by `,`'s.